# Not found: Op type not registered 'SqrtGrad' when creating Tensorflow Graph on Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, tensorflow, cc

As mentioned in the title, I am unable to create the Tensorflow graph from an imported model on Android using JNI. When attempting to run `tensorflow::Status s = session->Create(graph_def);`, the status returns `Not found: Op type not registered 'SqrtGrad'`.

I checked `jni-build/jni/include/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py`and `SqrtGrad` does exist. As running the model on Python does not return this error, could this be a problem when I generated my protobuf file with `tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, 'location', 'trained_model.pb', as_text=False)`?

Comment: Android targets are aggressively pruned to make them smaller, so some ops are left out and give "not registered" error when trying to use. This may be worth raising an issue for, here's an analogous issue -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3619

Comment: Also, perhaps the reason it's left out is because phone are usually used for inference, so an op like `SqrtGrad` wouldn't be used during inference. IE, it sounds like you are restoring a training graph with gradient nodes

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I managed to fix the first error (I think) but now new errors are popping up. To keep the question on topic, I created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561158/near-empty-frozen-graph-after-using-freeze-graph-from-tensorflow).

A more detailed explanation on how I fixed this problem can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5518#issuecomment-259935621)