# Near empty frozen graph after using freeze_graph from Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am currently trying to strip the training operations from my GraphDef so that I can run it on Android. However, to do so, I need to first freeze the graph using Tensorflow's `freeze_graph.py` script.

However, I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 331: invalid start byte` when attempting to run the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph \
--input_graph=/Users/leslie/Downloads/trained_model.pb \
--input_checkpoint=/Users/leslie/Downloads/Y6_1478303913_Leslie \
--output_graph=/tmp/frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=Y_GroundTruth
```

Could this be a problem in the way I created my graph and checkpoint? I created the input_graph via `tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, location, 'trained_model.pb', as_text=False)` and the checkpoint is created via `saver.save(sess, chkpointpath)`. Answers from StackOverflow say that the python script has non-ascii characters and that I should just simply strip them from the python script but I do not think that is such a great idea.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leslie/tensorflow-master/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow /python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 135, in <module>
tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/leslie/tensorflow-master/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/Users/leslie/tensorflow-master/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 132, in main
FLAGS.output_graph, FLAGS.clear_devices, FLAGS.initializer_nodes)
  File "/Users/leslie/tensorflow-master/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 98, in freeze_graph
text_format.Merge(f.read().decode("utf-8"), input_graph_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 331: invalid start byte
```

I also generated my protobuf file with `as_text = True` and the error above did not show up. However, I only got the following output.

```
Converted 0 variables to const ops.
1 ops in the final graph.
```

**Complete contents of "frozen_graph.pb"**

```
6

Y_GroundTruth��Placeholder*�
�dtype��0�*�
�shape��:
```

**Snippet of PB-file generation code:**

```
#Start all code before training code
    # Tensor placeholders and variables
    ...
    # Network weights and biases
    ...
    # Network layer definitions
    ...
    # Definition of cost function 
    ...
    # Create optimizer
    ...
    # Session operations
    ...
#END all code before training code

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, model_save_path)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, outputlocation, 'trained_model.pb', as_text=False)
```

Comment: Where does the the non-utf8 content comes from?

Comment: I am assuming it comes from my `input_graph`as I do not get the error when I generate the .PB-file as text instead of binary. However, When I attempt to run `freeze_graph` with the text .PB-file, it only contains 3 lines.

Comment: It looks like it's something to do with a field that's supposed to be a string (e.g. variable name), but contains binary data instead. Did you do anything like that?

Comment: Just wanted to say that it was a problem with how the protobuf file was generated (the variables in the protobuf file were not correctly initiated). Fixing the incorrect variable declarations fixed my problem.